RDP periodically stops working Ubuntu 24.04
first of all let me admit that I am quite new to the Linux game in general. I am currently running Ubuntu 24.04 (GNOME) in an PROXMOX VM accessing it from a Windows PC via RDP. I installed xrdp and configured my firewall to let RDP requests pass through. I also have the following startwm.sh config file, that I got from some other forum https://pastebin.com/3AB916tr.
I can access the VM and the desktop enviroment is working. However, after some time, when I connect via RDP the the screen is stays black and in the PROXMOX console window (which uses VNC i believe) I get the message that the GUI cannot be displayed do to another connection. Anyone any tips?
